# can't find openstack plugins for collectd

Tags: centos, openstack, collectd

I'm working on a VM centos 6.6 on witch I installed collectd to gather metrics, 
Everything is ok, but I want to edit some plugins to test collecting metrics from openstack that I've installed (single machine devstack)

I found this [link](https://github.com/rochaporto/collectd-openstack)
but the version was debian.

Is there an alternative solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found ans answer for my question, due to fpm command that converts debian packages to rpm and vice versa.

Try to use this link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-fpm-to-easily-create-packages-in-multiple-formats

fondly